# How to change content at a randomly selected time for 3 times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning Javascript and have done my research, but I am completely stuck.

I am working on project to create an auction style bidding page where I want to create an item page with a description and a "bid now" button. Once the button is clicked, I will show a "you're the highest bidder" message that will include a countdown with the code below:

```
var timer;
var totalSeconds;

function createTimer(timerID, time){
  timer = document.getElementById(timerID);
  totalSeconds = time;

  updateTimer()
  window.setTimeout("tick()", 1000);
}

function tick(){
if (totalSeconds <=0){
  return;
}

  totalSeconds -= 1;
  updateTimer()
  window.setTimeout("tick()",1000);
}

function updateTimer(){
  timer.innerHTML = (totalSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + totalSeconds;

}
```

What I'm having trouble figuring out is:

1. how to change the message to a "you've been outbidded" message when the countdown is any where from 1 - 3 seconds.
2. loop the function 3 times until the auction "ends"

If there are any references, please help.

Comment: for part 1 you can use `Math.ceil(Math.random()*3)` to get a random number from 1 to 3 and then subtract it from the remaining time, and use this amount in your setTimeout.

Comment: thank you @brybott. I've update the code to  
`function tick(){
  if (totalSeconds - Math.ceil(Math.random()*3) <=0 ){
    return;
  }`  Would you know how I could code when this ends to change the message?